# How to change a column value if it exists or insert a new column - Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

How do I update the 2nd field if the first field(primary key) exists or insert a new row in mysql (in a single query )?

```
INSERT INTO employee_lu(employeeId, employee_dept,CREATED_TS) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT "E1" AS cd, "DGSDFGSF" AS dept, NOW() AS created_ts) AS temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee_lu WHERE employeeId = "E1" and employee_dept = "DGSDFGSF")LIMIT 1
or if exists (SELECT 1 FROM employee_lu WHERE employeeId = "E1" )LIMIT 1
update employee_lu set employee_dept = "CCCC" WHERE employeeId = "E1"
```

If both employee Id and given dept exist thn don't do anything. if the employee id exist with different dept then update the old dept with new dept(given). if both not exist then insert new row.

Can some tell me how do I do this in single query ? It works fine if I just insert but not working if added update.

Just insert =

```
INSERT INTO employee_lu(employeeId, employee_dept,CREATED_TS) 
            SELECT * FROM (SELECT "F1" AS cd, "DGSDFGSF" AS description, NOW() AS created_ts) AS temp
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee_lu WHERE employeeId = "F1" and employee_dept = "DGSDFGSF")LIMIT 1;
```

But I need to update if the field has different value then the one we are searching for. Can some tell me how do I do this.

My table looks like :

```
CREATE TABLE `employee_lu` (
  `employeeId` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `employee_dept` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CREATED_TS` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `LAST_UPDATED_TS` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: thanks for the progress update.